# Why am i getting error: Too many rerenders in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to pass an array to another component. Data is a json object array with data in it. I know the data is there because when i click the button, the handleclick method is called and the data is displayed but when i try to pass that data as an array (seasondisplay and seasonlength) I get an error: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. How do i pass the data from the fetch as an array to the dropdown box component?

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  let seasons = [];

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/person', {
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.log("junk" + error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("");
  const handleClick = () => {
    setDisplay(
      data.map((item, i) => (
        <Text key={i}> {item.lastname} </Text>
      )))
  }
  const [seasondisplay, setSeasonDisplay] = useState("");
  const [seasonlength, setSeasonLengthDisplay] = useState(0);

    setSeasonDisplay(     
      data["lastname"]
    )

   setSeasonLengthDisplay (
     2
   )
    
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
        <DropDownChoice whichDropDown="Season" HowMany={seasonlength} ItemChoices={seasondisplay} />
        <DropDownChoice whichDropDown="Veggies" HowMany={4} ItemChoices={["carrots", "turnip", "peas", "corn"]} />
        <DropDownChoice whichDropDown="Fruit" HowMany={3} ItemChoices={["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]} />
        <Button
          title="Connect to DB"
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("please work");
            console.log(data);
            handleClick();
          }}
```

here is json:
[{"personid":11,"lastname":"cook","firstname":"ben","address":"north","city":"london"},{"personid":22,"lastname":"smith","firstname":"elaine","address":"main","city":"milton"}]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that:

You are changing state on each render by setSeasonDisplay. This state change cause re render and again in rendering you changing state. You have a loop.

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  let seasons = [];

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/person', {
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.log("junk" + error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("");
  const handleClick = () => {
    setDisplay(
      data.map((item, i) => (
        <Text key={i}> {item.lastname} </Text>
      )))
  }
  const [seasondisplay, setSeasonDisplay] = useState("");
  const [seasonlength, setSeasonLengthDisplay] = useState(0);

  //---------- changes 
  useEffect(() => {
      setSeasonDisplay(data["lastname"])
      setSeasonLengthDisplay (2)
   }, [data])
  //----------------
    
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
        <DropDownChoice whichDropDown="Season" HowMany={seasonlength} ItemChoices={seasondisplay} />
        <DropDownChoice whichDropDown="Veggies" HowMany={4} ItemChoices={["carrots", "turnip", "peas", "corn"]} />
        <DropDownChoice whichDropDown="Fruit" HowMany={3} ItemChoices={["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]} />
        <Button
          title="Connect to DB"
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("please work");
            console.log(data);
            handleClick();
          }}
```